# Kafka Streams API: unexpected delay consuming first event

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a simple Kafka producer that sends events to a kafka (0.10.2.0) topic ("my_kafka_topic"). It takes <10ms to read these events with `kafka-console-consumer`:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my_kafka_topic
```

However, I also have a very simple Kafka Streams app that reads events from the same topic and writes them to another topic ("my_kafka_topic_out"). In this app, **it takes around 2-4 minutes (not deterministic) to start receiving the events** from the same source topic.

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> stream = builder.stream("my_kafka_topic");
stream.to("my_kafka_topic_out");

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "steams-appid");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName());

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);
streams.start();
```

Once it starts receiving events, everything works as expected. Everything (kafka, zookeeper, kafka streams app) is running in localhost. What could be the issue? Is there any configuration parameter I could tune to reduce the delay so the Kafka streams app starts receiving events as fast as the console consumer?

**Edit:**

Apparently there is no delay if I set this config param (thanks @vmg), but I still don't understand why or whether it is a suitable value.

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, 5000);
```

Comment: Can you check your StreamsConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG and see if it defaults to roughly the delay you're experiencing? The [docs](http://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#start%28%29) indicate that a timeout might take place if the broker version cannot be verified

Comment: Thanks @vmg. It works when I set ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your update.

A similar issue occured in my environment too and I resolved by creating the topic before Kafka streams starts instead of setting

`ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG`.

**Did you create the topic before starting your app?**

In the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#streamsconfigs), `ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG` is that

> The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to proactively discover any new brokers or partitions.

So I guess that Kafka Streams app couldn't get the metadata which contains  the infomaintion about the target topic (and the relational borker) at starting.

And elapsed `METADATA MAX_AGE CONFIG(default 30000)`seconds force Kafka Streams app a refresh of the metadata, and after that, the new metadata contains the information about the topic and the app for the first time knows that the target topic has created.

In the other word, if I create the topic before starting Kafka Streams app, the app can get the metadata which contains the target topic at starting. And I have no need to wait to elapse `METADATA MAX_AGE` CONFIG seconds.